# Java Return between a int or String(unknown return type)

Tags: java, string, object, int, return

My program loads information from a text file and creates an array of an object with the information whether it is a integer or a string.

I then want the object to return either a String or an Integer depending on whether the object is holding a integer value or a string value.

edit...
So here is my type class that holds either a int if the field in the text file is a number, or a string if the field is a word, and this is held in a Type array.

```
public class Type {

  private String name;
  private int value;

  public Type(String name) {
      this.name = name;
  }

  public Type(int value) {
      this.value = value;
  }

  public String getName() {
      return this.name;
  }

  public int getValue() {
      return this.value;
  }

  public boolean isInt() {
      boolean isInt = false;
      if (this.value != 0) {
        isInt = true;
        return isInt;
      }
      return isInt;
  }

}
```

So in my array could be either a Int or a String, i want to return the datatype without any long statements in my main class.

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: We want to help you, but without a specific question we can't do anything. Please post your code (working or not), and specify the exact problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you strictly want only to get the specific values, you could add a method to your `Type` class and get the values from this method, ugly but does what you want:

```
public <T> T getDynamicValue(Type t) {
     if (isInt()) {
          return (T) ((Integer) t.getValue());
     } else {
          return (T) t.getName();
     }
}
```

use of it:

```
List<Type> dynamicList = Arrays.asList(new Type[]{new Type(1), new Type(2), new Type("dog")});
for (Type t : dynamicList) {
    System.out.println("T -> " + t.getDynamicValue(t));
}
```

If you want to perform some manipulation with this data, you have to make an `instanceof` check and Cast it, for instance some splitting (or String methods) with the name value...

Answer (score 1):

You can't choose the type of object to return at runtime. Your only option is to return an `Object`. You can check if it's a `String` or an `int` using this code, for example:

```
if(object instanceof String) {
   //... it's a string
}
else {
   //...otherwise it's an int
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are reading all inputs into String instances, you will need to test the values against Integer.parseString(value) to find out if it is actually an Integer.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to cast the object into an `Integer` and catch the `ClassCastException`:

```
try {
    int i = (Integer) object;
}
catch (ClassCastException e){
    String s = (String) object;
}
```

Comment: i think it will be better to use `instanceof` rather than catching exception

Answer (score 1):

When I have this type of problem, I sometimes solve it by turning the problem around and using a callback-style solution.

For example:

```
for ( Type t : array ) {
  t.process( callback );
}
```

Where the callback looks like this:

```
interface Callback {
  public void processInt(....);
  public void processString(....);
}
```

You can then either implement the process method either with an `if (isInt()) callback.processInt() else callback.processString()`, or if you change the definition of `Type` you can use the inheritance tree to do it for you.

For example:

```
interface Type {
  public void process( Callback cb );
}

class IntType implements Type {
  public void process( Callback cb ) {
    cb.processInt(...);
  }
}

class StringType implements Type {
  public void process( Callback cb ) {
    cb.processString(...);
  }
}
```